# simulate virtual users interacting with my .NET Winform or ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net

Microsoft release a product named - [Visual Studio Load Test Virtual User Pack 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/load-test-virtual-user-pack) to do that.

However, it cost USD$4,799.

So,is it other free or commercial tool can do simulate jobs?

At now, my solution is :

Winform :
3 x virtualbox + WinXP with some macro software.

ASP.NET
3 x virtualbox + WinXP + Firefox and iMacro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try a user interaction tester such as selenium

http://seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 1):

selenium is a great tool, but i have and still do prefer [watin](http://watin.org/).  Simply because I prefer writing the tests to recording.  but that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.loadtestingtool.com/ is an example. It records your navigation in web pages and reproduces it anytime you want. You can configure a lot of parameters to simulate paralel accesses.